# JavaScript value to BS Modal and then using value as c# variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, modal-dialog

this has been bothering me for the last few days and think I am just overthinking things.  I am opening up a bs modal dialog and passing it a value through the data-id attribute.  Can pass the value with no problem; I can also store it in a hidden field/div whatever.  However I need to pass that value to a razor function that brings back the rest of my record-set from the db and I am not using json to retrieve the records. I can convert the value but first must submit my form to get the value from the hidden field I stored it in.  I can always post it to another page but that would defeat the purpose of using the modal.  My question is since the 2 objects live in different states (server/client), how can I capture the ID as the modal is first launched with the ID. in this example I am passing the value to a div as well as hidden value.  I can capture the hidden value only after I submit the form! Thanks.

```
 <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg open_mymodal" id="cafeID" data-id="@item.ID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-yourparameter="@item.ID">Load</button>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">


            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                    </script>


                    @{ 
                        <div id="getIco">

                        </div>
                    }

                    <form action="~/modals.cshtml" name="test" method="post">

                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="IDRec" name="IDRec" />

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="getIco" name="getIco" value="" />
                        <input type="submit" name="name" value="submit" />
                    </form>

            @{
                   var recordID = request["IDRec"];
                   @recordID
             }

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>




$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var getmyID = button.data('id');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Here is the ID: ' + getmyID);
        modal.find('.modal-body #IDRec').val(getmyID);
        modal.find('.modal-body #getIco').val(getmyID);

    });
});
```

Comment: at this point any workaround would suffice, until I can refactor this whole piece.

Comment: I want to launch the modal and retrieve the rest of the data for that ID within the modal for editing/updating purposes of that record.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround that wont be pretty but will be functional.  uug...working too hard on this project!

sorry if I confused anyone; but essentially I was trying to populate the modal with my data-set and figured I would call the data I wanted through a c# function. Problem was I was capturing the id and then trying to use that id to get back the rest of the record set and display it for editing in the modal, however the id was in javascript.

instead of passing the id via javascript I can wrap the modal within my c# code and use the id that way...however since the record set is looping, on the client side the html may get bloated from the multiple instances of the modal, but will have an id generated along with the proper data for all the records.   Id' like a better option that does not have me creating multiple instance of the modal while in my loop. Ultimately, I may just have to use ajax or just call the record set from another page when I open the modal and have it load that way.   Ill leave the question  open, if folks have a better way.